# CDNResourceHandler stopped working in OmniFaces 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I updated OmniFaces version from 1.8.1 to 2.0 in my pom.xml. When I start the application, the resources are no longer resolved to the valid urls.

With OmniFaces 1.8.1:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://somedomain.com/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://somedomain.com/omnifaces/fixviewstate.js">
</script>
```

With OmniFaces 2.0:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://somedomain.com/omnifaces/fixviewstate.js">
```

Fragment of view's xhtml:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="publiclib" name="style.css"/>
<h:outputScript library="omnifaces" name="fixviewstate.js" target="head"/>
```

Fragment of faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>
         org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler
     </resource-handler>
     <resource-handler>
         org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler
     </resource-handler> 
</application>
```

Fragment of web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        publiclib:*=https://somedomain.com/*,
       omnifaces:*=https://somedomain.com/omnifaces/*,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_ALWAYS_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Application is running on WildFly 8.2 with PrimeFaces 5.1

Comment: Can you try 2.1 SNAPSHOT? There was a bug when more than one component library was included. E.g. PF + PF-Extensions.

Comment: I tried 2.1-SNAPSHOT but it did not work. I got again: RES_NOT_FOUND. 
In my pom.xml I have dependencies of: primefaces 5.1 primefaces-extensions 3.0.0 omnifaces 2.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce it with both 2.0 and 2.1 SNAPSHOT on exactly the mentioned environment (WF 8.2, PF 5.1, PE 3.0.0) with a blank project with only in the question mentioned configuration. I can only tell that `CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_ALWAYS_ENABLED` has been removed since 2.0 and that it's by default always enabled and there's now another context param to conditionally disable it based on an EL expression. But that shouldn't have any influence on your problem.

Comment: I tried different configurations and I did not managed to make it work.
Could you, please, try in your blank project add script to the google maps:
<h:outputScript library="google" name="maps.js" target="head"/> With  context-param org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS set to google:maps.js=https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true ?

Comment: I see it now. It would fail if `google:maps.js` actually doesn't exist in the WAR. It indeed "worked" in 1.x (although that was never been the intent). I will look closer at it tomorrow, it's now bed time :) For now, you could just place a physically existing (but perhaps empty) `google:maps.js` file in your webapp in order to fool it that it exists.

Comment: Adding empty files in the webapp resource folder which structure corresponds to the url defined in CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS context-param works. All in all it would be great to can have it working like in 1.x version ;) Thank you!

Comment: Before continuing, what exactly is the reason you can't just use `<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">`? The `CDNResourceHandler` is primarily intented to "capture" automatically included JSF resources and render a CDN URL for them.

Comment: @BalusC I can't answer for Jose but in my case it is because script tags seem to be added first in the head (no primefaces). So CDNResourceHandler would allow to have it rendered at the end if needed.